# How the Functional safety is acheived by protecting PDU at COM Layer?

Tags: autosar

**I have generated COM-Call Out for protection of safety related signal.currently  Its handled over COM Layer. Is there any other way to achieve functional safety concepts.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are other ways.
Check document "Overview of Functional Safety Measures in AUTOSAR" on the autosar.org homepage.

Comment: Yes, I have gone through the approaches which is mentioned in "Overview of Functional Safety Measures in AUTOSAR" document. this is much cleared to me now. but having issues for the generation of E2E protection wrapper

Comment: Forget the Protection Wrappers, use the E2EXf Transformers. The wrappers are not "standard" but just an example "appendix". The transformers are now official, and somehow also more performant.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, look into the newer AUTOSAR revisions (>4.2) and look into the AUTOSAR_EXP_LayeredSoftwareArchitecture about safety and the new Transformers. 
Actually, the ASIL SWC is the end and not your AUTOSAR Com. It could be fully ok, to have an QM ComStack. You could just use an Safety OS and Safety RTE.
The new transformers are also triggered out of an Rte_Read/Rte_Write, and you get the result back to your SWC that needs the safety check.